# Build react-native to IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have success to build a react-native application to an android signed apk. Now, Is that possible build (export) a react-native application to .ipa without using MAC? I'm using ubuntu linux btw

Answer (score 0):

To generate an `.ipa` you need a Mac or at least a `VM` with a `MAC` that has a `developer account` (something already bought if i'm not mistaken).